# Trying to install libgcc but getting error from postgres

Tags: postgresql, yum

I was trying to execute this command on my ubuntu machine:

```
yum install libgcc.i686
```

But getting this error which seems meaningless here:

```
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/common/redhat/rhel-%24releasever-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: pgdg-common. Please verify its path and try again
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling yum, but didn't work. How to solve this?

Comment: Ubuntu uses `apt` and `dpkg` to install packages, not `yum`.  So you're using invalid commands if you're on-topic with your question; though the error message is correct (try loading the URL into a browser and you'll confirm the error you're having).   Why are you using `yum` and what OS & release are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: This is a system library that you typically get when you install the GCC compiler. You may be in the process of wrecking your machine when you mess with that without knowing what you are doing. Please edit your question to make it clear exactly what you are trying to achieve and why.